# Is there a way to pass tags to SonarQube via maven command line?

Tags: maven, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube-scan

I am running the sonar-plugin in my Jenkinsfile. I'd like to pass some tags for the builds I am running. My projects consists of multiple modules (article, authentication) and I'd like to add `<moduleName>_<branchName>` as a SonarQube tag.

My maven command line I run in the Jenkinsfile looks like this:

```
sh "mvn -B -Dsonar.projectName=MyProject_${module}_${env.BRANCH_NAME} -Dsonar.projectKey=${Config.groupId}:${module}_${env.BRANCH_NAME} -Dsonar.host.url=${Config.sonarUrl}"
```

Is there any way to pass tags to SonarQube or do I have to apply them in SonarQube manually?

Comment: Did you consider using the new "branch" feature of the (paid) Developer Edition of SonarQube 6.7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [project_tags api](https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/web_api/api/project_tags/set), to set project tags. An example:

```
curl -XPOST http://your.sonarqube/api/project_tags/set?project=yourproject&tags=yourmodule_yourbranch
```

Comment: You can vote for this feature: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/add-tags-through-maven-pom-file/28611